# Google Charts: How to set Column max value and without big gap in between. (Columns)

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Current I am using  "Top-X Chart" format to code out.
https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#data-format

However I would like to set the Y-axis Highest value 2000 and display it out, instead of following the Data I added in.
Second Problem, by using this format there have a big gap in between, I want them to shown side by side. How should I do it?
Below is my code:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/wacy5mvv/
  google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:['corechart',"bar"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

      function drawStuff() {
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['date', 'pax'],
          ["12-05-2015", 60],
          ["12-06-2015", 31],
          ['12-06-2017', 3]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Report Chart',
          width: 900,
          legend: { position: 'none' },
          chart: { subtitle: 'Number Of Pax' },
          axes: {
            x: {
              0: { side: 'bottom', label: 'Date'} // Top x-axis.
            }
          },
          bar: { groupWidth: "10%" }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
        // Convert the Classic options to Material options.
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      };
```

I Know by using this google chart will be more useful for me however I not really understand the code:https://jsfiddle.net/u6fdbd6L/1/ 
e.g. 

-Unable to understand why the v,min and max got 3 argument 

-when I change the format to string got some problem.
etc

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Motivation Level');

      data.addRows([
        [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '19-08-2014'}, 1],
        [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: '19-08-2014'}, 2],
        [{v: [10, 0, 0], f:'19-08-2014'}, 3],
        [{v: [11, 0, 0], f: '19-08-2014'}, 4]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Motivation Level Throughout the Day',
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time of Day',
          format: 'h:mm a',
          viewWindow: {
            min: [7, 30, 0],
            max: [17, 30, 0]
          }
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Number of Pax'
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
        document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set width of a group of bars using `bar.groupWidth` property, example below demonstrates how to set no space between them:

```
bar: { 
    groupWidth: '100%'
}
```

`vAxis.viewWindowMode` property specifies how to scale the vertical axis to render the values within the chart area, the example below demonstrates how to set vertical maximum  value to `100`:

```
vAxis: {  
    viewWindow: { max: 100 }
}
```

**Complete example**

```js
google.load("visualization", "1.1", { packages: ['corechart', "bar"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['date', 'pax'],
      ["12-05-2015", 60],
      ["12-06-2015", 31],
      ['12-06-2017', 3]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Report Chart',
        width: 900,
        legend: { position: 'none' },
        chart: { subtitle: 'Number Of Pax' },
        axes: {
            x: {
                0: { side: 'bottom', label: 'Date' } // Top x-axis.
            }
        },
        bar: { 
           groupWidth: '100%'
        },
        vAxis: {  
            viewWindow: { max: 500 },
            format: '000'
        }    
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
    // Convert the Classic options to Material options.
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
};
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="top_x_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

**Update**

```js
google.load("visualization", "1.1", { packages: ['corechart', "bar"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['date', 'pax'],
      ["12-05-2015", 60],
      ["12-06-2015", 31],
      ['12-06-2017', 3]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Report Chart',
        legend: { position: 'none' },
        chart: { subtitle: 'Number Of Pax' },
        axes: {
            x: {
                0: { side: 'bottom', label: 'Date' } // Top x-axis.
            }
        },
        bar: { 
           groupWidth: '100%'
        },
        vAxis: {  
            viewWindow: { min: 0, max:200 },
            format: '000'
        },
        width: 420,
        height: 640
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
};
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="top_x_div"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, If I want width remain 20% but the bar will be display side by side at the left area. Possible to make it ? 

However the viewWindow: { max: 500}, was working well :)